# apt-get install -f

Tags: apt, dpkg

Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,
Dear Madams and Sirs,

I use Ubuntu 20.04.6. LTS.
After an actualisatien i get an information that somthing was wrong and i should fix it it in the terminal. There i get the following massage after the order:
sudo apt-get install -f;

*E: Sperre /var/lib/dpkp/lock-frontend konnte nicht erlangt werden. Sie wird von Prozess 89203 (aptd) gehalten  [lock /var/lib/dpkp/lock-frontend couldnt get. It was holded by prozess 89203 (aptd)]

N: Beachten Sie, dass das Entfernen der Sperrdatei keine Lösung ist und Ihr System beschädigen kann.  [notice that the deleting of the lockfile was not an solution and your system could be damaged]*

*E: Erlangen der Sperre für die Dpkg-Oberfäche (/var/lib/lock-frontend) nicht möglich; wird sie von einem anderen Prozess verwendet [get the lock for the user interface (/var/lib/lock-frontend) not possible cause it was used by an other prozess]
?*

So maybe you can tell me whats going on and how i now should do for fixing this problem.

Many thanks and
kindly regards
Jens Kynast

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly what it says in the error message: there is a process called `aptd` that has reserved exclusive access to the local package database, so the `apt` command you started cannot get access.

The way to solve it is to either shut down aptd, perform the repair, and start it again, or find out how to perform the repair through aptd.

Presumably, the former is easier.